# node repl catch ctrl+d

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop, keystroke

I'm using `require('repl').start()` to open up an interactive terminal to interact with my node app, but due to muscle memory I keep killing the process when I hit control-d mistakenly trying delete-forward. Is there anyway I can catch this keystroke/character and ignore it or rebind it to have more emacs-like behavior?

Answer (score 1):

```js
repl_server.on('exit', ()=>{ process.exit() })
```

Change `process.exit()` to your desired behavior

Comment: When I try this out I'm still seeing the repl close. Do you have an examples or documentation that describe the expected behavior?